# How to separate icon and input type text box and to move the div to the right corner?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Expected output:

[image: expected output]

Actual output:

[image: actual output]

The background image got zoomed not as same and the div is not moving to right, i need to separate the icon and  text box with black line that too not working.

my login.js is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import css from './login.css'
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';

import logo from '../images/pam-logo-.png';

export default class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{width:"350px",height:"320px"}}>
            <form className="login-form" style={{marginTop:"20px"}} >
                <FormGroup>
                <img src={logo} width="150" height="70" style={{marginLeft:"65px"}} />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Input type="email" id="icon1" placeholder="Enter Email Address" style={{width: "250px",marginLeft:"13px"}} />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                    <Input type="password" id="icon2" placeholder="Enter Password"  style={{width: "250px",marginLeft:"13px"}} />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                    <Button color="info"  style={{width:"250px",marginLeft:"13px"}}>Login</Button>
                    </FormGroup>


            </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

my login.css is:

```
@media all and (min-width: 480px) {
    .Login {
      padding: 60px 0;
    }

    .Login form {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 320px;
    }
  }
  .logindiv
{
  margin-left:50px ;
}
.login-form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;

  }

  #icon1{
    background: white url(../images/login-mail.png) left no-repeat;
    padding-left: 37px;
    margin-left: 37px;
  }

  #icon2{
    background: white url(../images/login-password.png) left no-repeat ;
    padding-left: 37px;
    margin-left: 37px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid black;

  }
  .col {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
  }
```

Any ideas please..!if i move the div the background white space only enlarging not the elements, and the div is also need as curved in expected output

Comment: Can you edit your snippets to be a [mcve]? Be minimal, remove everything useless to showcase your problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please create a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example In this case, you could add a StackBlitz with React

Comment: Did you look at this? https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/input-group/

Comment: @Roy I have just added only two input fields and one button so its the minimal reproducible snippet and my problem is mentioned that this container has to be moved so i written the div fully and i need the background image as orginal not in zoomed layout

Comment: @ChrisG yes but the example is inbuilt icon but i am using custom icon

Comment: Implement them as background images: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-darwin-6y5cz

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Email address field and Password field inside a div as below.

```
<div class="email_wrap">
                    <Input type="email" id="icon1" placeholder="Enter Email Address"/>
</div>
<div class="password_wrap">
<Input type="password" id="icon2" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
</div>
    <style>
.email_wrap{width:100%;float:left;position:relative;}
.password_wrap{width:100%;float:left;position:relative;}
.email_wrap::before{content:url(../images/login-mail.png);position:absolute;left:5px;top:5px;}
.password_wrap::before{content:url(../images/login-password.png);position:absolute;left:5px;top:5px;}
</style>
```

Note: Adjust the top and left CSS of the BEFORE element based on your design to suit your design.